# Convert SQLITE to MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlite, sql-delete

Can someone help me convert this into MYSQL since IN is not supported in MYSQL . Should i use INNER JOIN? but how?

```
DELETE from SSLDOMAINS_logstable where id IN (SELECT id from SSLDOMAINS_logstable order by id asc limit 50)
```

Comment: *since IN is not supported in MYSQL* This is incorrect. It's supported.

Comment: @Akina I think you're wrong. [MySQL DELETE Documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/delete.html) states that "You cannot delete from a table and select from the same table in a subquery."

Comment: @stack_lech Study the [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=c74fdb11362374a5dbe07d18c3cb198c). And try to understand what does the word ***same*** mean in the documentation text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only need the ORDER BY clause and LIMIT in MySql:

```
DELETE FROM SSLDOMAINS_logstable 
ORDER BY id
LIMIT 50
```

This query will delete the first 50 rows of the table ordered by `id` ascending.

Comment: If `id` is not unique then your query result will differ from the result of original query execution on SQLite.

Comment: *If id is not unique..* Correct. So the requirement needs clarification by the OP.

Answer (score 0):

```
DELETE t1.*
FROM SSLDOMAINS_logstable t1
JOIN ( SELECT t2.id 
       FROM SSLDOMAINS_logstable t2
       ORDER BY id ASC 
       LIMIT 50 ) t3 ON t1.id = t3.id
```

If id is unique (including primary), see [forpas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10498828/forpas)'s solution. But if not... subquery selects least 50 id values, query deletes records with these id values - i.e. LIMIT in this case works like "LIMIT WITH TIES"

Comment: Please add some/short explanation to your answer.

Comment: @mattfreake You have lost the reference link during edition. This is unacceptable. PS. The link restored.

Comment: This helped a lot, Thanks @Akina